# accumulator returns undefined within making `reduce` method

Tags: javascript, reduce

I tried to make a function working same as `Array.prototype.reduce` method.

```js
function a(collection, iterator, accumulator) {

    for (i of Object.keys(collection)){
      if (i===0 && accumulator === undefined){
          accumulator = collection[i]
          continue
      }

      accumulator = iterator(accumulator, collection[i])
    }

    return accumulator;
  };



a([1,2,3],function(acc,cur){return acc += cur}, 0) // this works fine. returns 6
a([1,2,3],function(acc,cur){return acc += cur}) // expected 6 but returns NaN
a([1,2,3], function(memo){return memo}); // expected 1 but returns undefined
```

I don't know why `accumulator` does not set as `collection[i]` and keep stayed as `undefined` when the initial value (the third parameter of function a) not delivered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Object.keys` always returns an array of **strings**, so `i` is a string, so `i === 0` is always false.

Also note that you need to declare `i`. Right now, your code is falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). (I suggest using strict mode so they're the error they always should have been.)

FWIW, here's the minimum update addressing both of those (but see below as well):

```js
"use strict";
function a(collection, iterator, accumulator) {
    let first = true;                            // ***
    for (const i of Object.keys(collection)){
    //   ^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− *** declare `i`
        if (first && accumulator === undefined){
    //      ^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− *** first pass?
            first = false;                       // ***
            accumulator = collection[i]
            continue
        }
        first = false;                           // ***

        accumulator = iterator(accumulator, collection[i])
    }

    return accumulator;
};

console.log(a([1,2,3],function(acc,cur){return acc += cur}, 0));
console.log(a([1,2,3],function(acc,cur){return acc += cur}));
console.log(a([1,2,3], function(memo){return memo}));
```

---

FWIW, I don't know if you meant it to be an exact match for `reduce`, but if so the logic of your function is not the same as the logic of `Array.prototype.reduce`. See [the specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.reduce) for details, but `reduce` checks how many arguments it got, it doesn't check to see if the accumulator is `undefined`. If you explicitly give it the value `undefined` for the accumulator, it will use that value (rather than using the first array element's value):

```js
console.log("`undefined` for accumulator:");
["a", "b", "c"].reduce((acc, value) => { console.log(acc, value); return value; }, undefined);

console.log("No accumulator:");
["a", "b", "c"].reduce((acc, value) => { console.log(acc, value); return value; })
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

The accumulator can also *become* `undefined` during the reduction. And if there's no accumulator given, it's the first value seen (not necessarily at index 0 in a sparse array!) that's used. (My fix for the accumulator above actually fixes that as a by-product.) Your code also uses `Object.keys` whereas `reduce` just uses a `for` loop. I didn't do a close read, there could be other discrepancies as well.

```js
"use strict";
function a(collection, iterator, ...optional) {  // ***
    let haveAccumulator = optional.length > 0;   // *** Default acc correctly
    let [accumulator] = optional;                // ***
    for (const i of Object.keys(collection)){
    //   ^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− *** declare `i`
        if (!haveAccumulator) {                  // ***
            haveAccumulator = true;              // ***
            accumulator = collection[i]
            continue;
        }

        accumulator = iterator(accumulator, collection[i])
    }

    return accumulator;
};



console.log(a([1,2,3],function(acc,cur){return acc += cur}, 0));
console.log(a([1,2,3],function(acc,cur){return acc += cur}));
console.log(a([1,2,3], function(memo){return memo}));
```

Comment: Thanks to teach me things that I totally don't understand and even noticed at all. Love your answer